# Django - Copying model field to another field

Tags: python, django, debugging, model

I did a lot of search but couldn't find a proper way to do it.
I want to copy some model object data to another model object data.
I've added my codes below. I got 3 models. as you can see I got a FK ,
the Receipt model related with receipt field. when I want to add Receiptitem object I wanna copy amount , vat and total_amount exactly.
I didn't understad save method.

the user will add product and receipt. then When user will try to select ReceiptItem receipt and product droplists he will choose object he wants and the other stuff will get auto. I wanted to do this.

```py
class Receipt(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    vat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.total_amount)

class ReceiptItem(models.Model):
    receipt = models.ForeignKey('Receipt', on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    vat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    vat_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    sub_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vat_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data to be copied over upon saving your `ReceiptItem` you can overload the `save` function of the model like this:

```
class ReceiptItem(models.Model):
    # your fields here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.vat = self.receipt.vat
        # copy the other data you need here

        # the line below calls Model.save() which commits
        # your changes to the database
        super(ReceiptItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Another option can be to set the values in `ReceiptItem.__init__()` if you need the values before the object is saved to database.